# Exceção na validação Request do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma Request que faz a validação dos dados. Uma das validações é o `unique` para restringir a repetição dos itens. Porém, os itens são cadastrados em categorias. Preciso que quando o item for de outra categoria, ele deixe fazer o cadastro.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'preco'         => 'required',
        'categoria'     => 'required',
        'insumo'        => 'required|min:3|max:100|unique:insumos,insumo,'.$this->id,
    ];
}
```

'insumo' esse é o valor que preciso liberar a duplicação, caso a categoria que esteja recebendo no formulário seja diferente da que já está cadastrada no banco.

por exemplo:

```
Id - Insumo - Categoria - Preço
1  - Tomate -    5      - 1.00
```

se cadastrar outro "Tomate", mas a categoria for outro valor, ele deixe cadastrar.

Alguém consegue imaginar uma forma de fazer isso ?

Ficando assim no banco de dados:

```
Id - Insumo - Categoria - Preço
1  - Tomate -    5      - 1.00
2  - Tomate -    7      - 1.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma validação personalizada com a linha de comando:

> `php artisan make:rule CategoryInputUnique`

gerando na pasta `app\rules` uma classe `CategoryInputUnique`, dentro possui um método com a seguinte assinatura `passes($attribute, $value)` onde deve escrever um código para busca no banco de dados se há repetição desse nome com esse número de categoria (*vale lembrar que é bom criar um índice nesses dois campos pelo banco de dados*), exemplo:

```
<?php namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CategoryInputUnique implements Rule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $categoria = request('categoria', 0);
        $id = (int)request('id', 0);
        $result = DB::table('insumos')
            ->where('insumo', '=', $value)
            ->where('categoria', '=', $categoria);
        if ($id === 0) {
            return $result->count() === 0;
        }
        $model = $result->first();
        if ($model) {
            return (int)$model->id === $id;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

nesse código vai verificar se há repetição, onde foi informado de forma aleatória nome da tabela (coloque o nome real da sua tabela) e os dois campos categoria e insumo (coloque aqui também de acordo com a sua tabela) e vai contar se há registros com essas duas informações.

Para utilizar é só declarar no `array` de validação a sua instância:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'preco' => 'required',
        'categoria' => 'required',
        'insumo' => ['required', 
                     'min:3',
                     'max:100', 
                     function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                        $categoria = request('categoria', 0);
                        $id = (int)request('id', 0);
                        $result = DB::table('insumos')
                            ->where('insumo', '=', $value)
                            ->where('categoria', '=', $categoria);
                        if ($id === 0) {
                            if (!($result->count() === 0)){
                                $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
                            }
                        }
                        $model = $result->first();
                        if ($model) {
                            if (!((int)$model->id === $id)) {
                                $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
                            }
                        }
                        return true;                        
                     }
        ],
    ];
}
```

---

Pode utilizar o método `facade` para criar uma extensão dentro da classe `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('categoriainputunique', function (
             $attribute, 
             $value, 
             $parameters, 
             $validator
    ) {
        $categoria = request('categoria', 0);
        $id = (int)request('id', 0);
        $result = DB::table('insumos')
            ->where('insumo', '=', $value)
            ->where('categoria', '=', $categoria);
        if ($id === 0) {
            return $result->count() === 0;
        }
        $model = $result->first();
        if ($model) {
            return (int)$model->id === $id;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

e na validação chame somente pelo nome da extensão:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'preco' => 'required',
        'categoria' => 'required',
        'insumo' => ['required', 'min:3','max:100', 'categoriainputunique'],
    ];
}
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)
- [Custom Validation Rules - Using Rule Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects)
- [Custom Validation Rules - Using Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures)
- [Custom Validation Rules - Using Extensions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-extensions)

Comment: funcionando 100% vlw Mestre! você é um monstro!